# Entity Framework Core with SQLite: ASP.NET application holding onto database in memory

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm using my Mac to develop and ASP.NET Core application with SQLite as the database (when learning about SQLite and EF Core, I read through this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite). Migrations and updating the database schema are working, but it seems as though the ASP.NET application is holding onto the database in memory.

Two reasons I'm assuming this:

1. When I use "DB Browser For SQLite" to browse the SQLite the database schema and data, it shows that there is no data in any of the table (schema is present, so migrations are writing to disk)
2. When I deleted the SQLite database file itself, the ASP.NET site still had the old data from the deleted file!  Really weird.

Does anyone know how I can have my application actually write out the data to the SQLite file, and prevent it from storing it in memory?

Thanks again!

DbContext file:

```
public class EssBomContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Part> Parts { get; set; }
    // Other DbSets removed for brevety

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=sqlite.db");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I can't see your code, but to save out to database, you must call  SaveChanges() on the DbContext.

Comment: it will always store in memory till you actually save as @JoshuaWaring indicated also there will be some tracking for changes to records too

Comment: Thanks for the response Joshua and mvermef.  Unfortunately, I cannot share my code in a public repo.  Yes, I an indeed calling .SaveChanges() when I do an update or create, and it does save it in memory.  But that doesn't explain why the code is holding onto the data even when I delete the SQLite db file and stop the webserver (ctrl+c in the command line when 'dotnet run' command is running... I'm running the .NET CLI).

Comment: I believe I found the issue!  I have several projects in my Solution: a Web project, a Services (business layer) project, and a Data.EF project (which has the DbContext).  When I run the 'dotnet ef database update' command in the same folder as the Data.EF folder, it creates the db file in this folder. However, when either running the debugger in Visual Studio for Mac (aka Community) or running 'dotnet run', it creates another db file in the Web project!  So, it is saving, but in a different folder.  The 'dotnet ef database update' command doesn't run in the Web project.

Comment: How can I have the Web project use the db in the Data.EF project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How can I have the Web project use the db in the Data.EF project?"

Possibly `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=\Data.EF\sqlite.db");`